# knockout.js applyBindings corrupts existing bindings when using getElementById

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, append

I first use applyBindings() to apply my model to the document:

```
ko.applyBindings(appViewModel);
```

Then I append some dynamic content:

```
$('#contentSection').append(myAccountTmpl);
```

Then I use the applyBindings to apply the model to the new content.  If I use getElementById to reference the dynamically added node, the bindings on the document are corrupted.  If I use the JQuery style of reference I have no problem:

```
  ko.applyBindings(appViewModel,document.getElementById('#myAccountForm'));  //corrupts other bindings
  ko.applyBindings(appViewModel,$('#myAccountForm')[0]);  //No Problems!
```

If anyone can suggest an explanation for this behavior, it would be appreciated.  I am new to these technologies, and have no clues.  I can't really even explain what I mean by "corruption" except that certain bindings fail to show the content (I did verify that the data was still in the bound model property).

Also, this might help someone else having inexplicable 'corruption' with their bindings.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `document.getElementById` don't prefix it with hash. Form with hash is selector syntax. `getElementById` expect id name so for your version it return null. Correct form is:

```
ko.applyBindings(appViewModel,document.getElementById('myAccountForm'));
```